# How to put the equation right at figure?

Tags: floats, equations

[image]

I want to put the equation right at the figure and center they both. How I can realize it?

Comment: So the image shows what you're after, not what you've tried, right? How did you get the image?

Comment: It's just sketch created in the other program.

Comment: Thanks for editing! I don't know about this tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would place the graphic and equation in the following way:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[valign = c, width = .3\linewidth]{example-image} \qquad
  $\displaystyle A = \frac{B}{C}$
  \caption{A picture and an equation}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The image would be vertically aligned at the `c`enter with the `\displaystyle` equation, thanks to [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox)'s `export` of options.

You don't have to add the caption, nor do you have to place it inside a `figure` float. You could also just use:

```
\[
  \includegraphics[valign = c, width=.3\linewidth]{example-image} \qquad
  A = \frac{B}{C}
\]
```

Comment: Yes; I guess this is more like what the OP wants. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: It's nice solution for "includegraphics", but there are more "tikzpicture" in my work (it doesn't have "valign" option). I will try to think out...

Comment: I used "baseline={([yshift=-.8ex]current bounding box.center)}". Result is near to one that I want to get...

Comment: @iVi: Sorry, but I didn't see you mouse being drawn using a `tikzpicture`... :)

Comment: It is so bad code, but it work.
http://pastebin.com/jYtGbaxQ

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot about this aspect. But your answer is good and it can help other people. I will more accurate select pictures at the future :)

Comment: great code, but I'm wondering how to add separate caption for the figure and code.

Comment: @Z-Y00: Perhaps consider using `minipage`s: [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/wC2w01FD), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJoJX.png).

Comment: Make sure you add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}`